# Crashing SQL server - SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, magento-community, sql

Magento Community v. 1.7.0.2
PHP Version 5.3.21
SQL Version: 5.0.96-community
O/S: Linux

To clear this error, I can empty my 'var/cache' directory and the website will work for approx. 10 minutes, then it will revert back to this error. This error is effecting our e-mail system as well! We are running a VPS so we do not have access to SSH. I've already tried restoring our 'app' and 'lib' directory from a recent backup and this has not worked/

Any ideas to help?

This seems to have randomly started happening. When visiting my website, an error occurs and you can view the error below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`specs`, `e`.`type`, `e`.`warranty`, `e`.`drainsize`, `e`.`dimensions`, `e`.`included_in_box`, `e`.`brand`, `e`.`ada_compliant_fe`, `e`.`aerator_clearance_fe`, `e`.`brand_value`, `e`.`dimensions_fe`, `e`.`downloads`, `e`.`faucet_height_fe`, `e`.`faucet_holes`, `e`.`faucet_holes_value`, `e`.`faucet_mount_style`, `e`.`faucet_mount_style_value`, `e`.`finish`, `e`.`gauge`, `e`.`material`, `e`.`material_value`, `e`.`series_fe`, `e`.`sink_base_size`, `e`.`sink_bowl_layout`, `e`.`sink_bowl_layout_value`, `e`.`sink_mount_type`, `e`.`spout_reach_fe`, `e`.`upc`, `e`.`warranty_fe`, `e`.`video`, `e`.`surface_texture`, `e`.`surface_texture_value`, `e`.`room` FROM `ds_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `ds_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id IN (789) WHERE (e.visibility != 1) AND (((((e.news_from_date <= '2014-07-25 11:06:10') OR (e.news_from_date IS null))))) AND (((((e.news_to_date >= '2014-07-25 11:06:10') OR (e.news_to_date IS null))))) AND ((`e`.`news_from_date` IS not null) OR (`e`.`news_to_date` IS not null)) ORDER BY `e`.`name` asc LIMIT 1


Trace:
#0 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#6 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#7 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1047): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT DISTINCT...')
#8 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(301): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 /home/sinks/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/em_new_products/new_grid.phtml(36): Varien_Data_Collection->getItems()
#11 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sinks/pub...')
#12 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#13 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/local/EM/Newproducts/Block/List.php(34): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): EM_Newproducts_Block_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Template/Filter.php(76): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 [internal function]: Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter->widgetDirective(Array)
#18 /home/sinks/public_html/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#19 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(502): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<h5>Popular Ite...')
#20 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/local/EM/Megamenupro/Block/Megamenupro.php(27): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<h5>Popular Ite...')
#21 /home/sinks/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/galayomarket/template/em_megamenupro/showmenu.phtml(2): EM_Megamenupro_Block_Megamenupro->getMegamenupro()
#22 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sinks/pub...')
#23 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#24 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/local/EM/Megamenupro/Block/Megamenupro.php(37): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): EM_Megamenupro_Block_Megamenupro->_toHtml()
#27 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#29 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#31 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('area01', true)
#33 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/local/EM/Themeframework/Helper/Theme.php(82): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('area01')
#34 /home/sinks/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/galayomarket/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(43): EM_Themeframework_Helper_Theme->display(Object(Mage_Page_Block_Html), '2columns-right')
#35 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/sinks/pub...')
#36 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#37 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#38 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#39 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#40 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#41 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#42 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#43 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#44 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#45 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#46 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#47 /home/sinks/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#48 /home/sinks/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#49 /home/sinks/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#50 {main}
```

Comment: What did you restart apache + mysql already?

Comment: so from the trace I see that you have a custom module doing something, I would suggest that the problem is somewhere in the customer moduel. What does it do and how does it do it?

Comment: Can you turn off the newproducts ext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I fixed it correctly but it's now working. I cleaned the cache/sessions and then disabled the Cache  via Cache Management. After re-enabling the Cache via Cache Management, the error is gone and the store is functioning as it should.